# I keep getting the error message '{' expected public class TwoDimArray when using ubuntu. What could be the issue?

Tags: java, ubuntu

```
package twodimarray;

public class TwoDimArray 
{

    public static void main(String[] args) 
    {
        int[][]Table = new int[12][12];
        TwoDimArray(Table);
    }

    public static void TwoDimArray(int[][] Table)
    {

        int row = 0;
        int col = 0;

        for(row = 0; row < Table.length; row++)
        {
            for(col = 0; col < Table[row].length; col++)
            {
                Table[row][col] = row * col;
            }
        }

        for(row = 0; row < Table.length; row++)
        {
            for(col = 0; col < Table.length; col++)
            {
                System.out.printf("%3d ", Table[row][col]);
            }
            System.out.printf("\n");
        }
        System.out.println("-------------------------------------------------");
    }

}
```

This program is meant to a create a 12 x 12 table of multiplication.
For some odd reason, this code works without a problem on netbeans but fails to run on Ubuntu. I had tried placing this bracket on various lines of code but only ended up making more errors, I would really appreciate it if someone could give me an idea where it can be solved.

Comment: How do you compile it ? I have tried and I have no error

Comment: What does "fails to run" mean? What is the error?

Comment: I apologize for the confusion, Im a bit new to java. A better explanation would be that this code works on netbeans just fine, but when I tried to compile it using the terminal from ubuntu, it keeps giving me the error that says bracket expected.

Comment: This is what I did. Terminal > nano TwoDimArray.java> "Typed the code" > save and exit back to terminal> gedit TwoDimArray.java> javac TwoDimArray.java> Error, '{' expected public class TwoDimArray.

Answer (score 0):

The file `TwoDimArray.java` should be in a subdirectory *twodimarray* of your sources directory, as you declare it to be in the `twodimarray`package. It may already be there as Netbeans compiles it.

When you compile from the commandline, you have to start the compilation from the top of the sources directory by using:

```
javac twodimarray/TwoDimArray.java
```

Because you call `javac`from the same directory as the java file itself, the java compiler assumes that the java class must has no package and therefore complains because the class definition is not first in the file, although I have to say that an error message complaining about the wrong package definition would have been better.